# How to have emacs format/indent javadoc comments correctly?

Tags: indentation, formatting, java

Very new to emacs.  (I only started day before yesterday.)  I'm writing some Java and was wondering if there's an option or something I can set up so it will indent Javadoc comments correctly.

What I mean by that is, if I type:

```
public class NiftyClass {

    /*
     * Here's what this method does.
     *
     * @return the answer
     */
```

every time I hit enter to start a new line in the Javadoc comments the pointer is at the left margin.  Inside the body of a method when I hit enter it takes me to the next line at the correct indentation.  I'd prefer that it do something similar with these comments, such that the pointer aligns itself underneath the previous *.  Or, better yet, that it add the next *space for me and start me right after that.

Is there anything that can do this?

Comment: `M-j` opens new line in comments, but what exactly it does depends on the mode settings. It is bound to `comment-indent-new-line`.

Comment: M-j does exactly what I wanted!  Thank you!

Comment: @wvxvw If you want to repost your comment below, I'd mark it as the answer :]

Comment: I think phils had a better explanation (`M-j` could be bound to something other than `comment-indent-new-line`, but in general Emacs user would learn to expect `M-j` to continue comment on a new line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try:

```
(electric-indent-mode +1)

(defun my-newline-and-indent-mode-hook ()
  (local-set-key (kbd "RET") (key-binding (kbd "M-j")))
  (local-set-key (kbd "<C-return>") #'electric-indent-just-newline))

(add-hook 'prog-mode-hook #'my-newline-and-indent-mode-hook)
```

Pressing <kbd>return</kbd> will continue comment or newline-and-indent -- press <kbd>C-return</kbd> to end the comment with a plain newline.

Comment: Instead of `(key-binding (kbd "M-j"))`, you can just use `"M-j"` for (essentially) the same effect. But the right way is to use the actual function name.

Comment: Malabarba: No, there's a very good reason for doing it as Fromage has shown -- that key binding (`M-j`) is standard for this functionality, but the function it's bound to can vary between major modes. Simply making `RET` do the same thing as `M-j` is a simpler and more-reliable approach.

Comment: And given that this is for `prog-mode-hook`, setting a single specific function for this would be *wrong*, for the same reasons. You would need a map of exceptions to go with it.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9058889/cannot-get-to-bind-enter-to-newline-and-indent-in-emacs-very-annoying